# Javascript Graphical Relations Symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, entity-relationship

I have two entities in my symfony2 system, which are related in a 1:1 relationship, with null posible. What I want is a kind of graphical editor to "drag-and-drop" or "draw" these connections graphically via eg Javascript. Is there any Javascript library which I can use to display the current relations and save the changes?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for: you want a graphical representation of the relations between your doctrine entities?

Comment: well yes, kind of. what I am searching for first of all is a javascript library that allows displaying graphs (with bubbles for entities / objects and edges for the relations) - ok you actually brought me on that keyword "graph" which definately helped me using google :D